# Forcing http to https append "public" in URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` inside `webroot` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/admin/)
    RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, inside `public` directory I have the following `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

    # Force HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

Then, if I hit the following URL:

http://example.com/

The browser is redirected to:

https://example.com/public/

When site is loaded over HTTP (without forcing), this part is omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force `https` rule must be placed in root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

   # Force HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/admin/)
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Remove `http->https` rule from `public/.htaccess` and clear browser cahce to test this.